# console application and async await example is blocking

Tags: c#, async-await

Why is the following example blocking? I was expecting "Run First" to run immediately and then 5 seconds later the "Run Last" would appear.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Call SomeAsyncCode() somehow
            SomeAsyncCode().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.WriteLine("Run First");
        }

        private static async Task SomeAsyncCode()
        {
            // Use await here!
            await Task.Delay(5000);

            Console.WriteLine("Run Last");
            // Other async goodness...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are *awaiting* (term used loosely) the task.

It would make more sense if you didn't use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` (which are internal framework methods anyway) and just wrote

```
SomeAsyncCode().Wait();
Console.WriteLine("Run First");
```

It then becomes obvious whats happening, you are waiting for the task to complete.

The following is probably more like what you expect;

```
// start task
var task = SomeAsyncCode();

Console.WriteLine("Run First");

task.Wait();
```

In all honesty though, it should be rare to need to call, `Wait`, `Result` or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on an `async` method, doing so in a *UI* app, or something with a *Synchronization Context* will likely cause a deadlock

Ideally you let `async` and `await` propagate, in *C# 7.1* and higher you have the ability to create an `async` *Entry Point* which allows you use the *Async and Await Pattern* in a more succinct manner

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await SomeAsyncCode();
    Console.WriteLine("Run First");
}
```

or

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{     
    var task = SomeAsyncCode();
    Console.WriteLine("Run First");
    await Task.WhenAll(task);
}
```

Comment: you need C# 7.1 to define async `Main` method

Answer (score 1):

When you define `async Task Method()` - you are telling that this method should be awaited even though it will return nothing.

When you define `async void Method()` - you are telling that this is **fire'n'forget** method and you don't want to await it.

Also, when you `void Main(string[] args)` is returning - your application is closing and GC will kill all your tasks.

So, your code should be more like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Call SomeAsyncCode() somehow
    SomeAsyncCode();

    Console.WriteLine("Run First");
    Console.ReadKey(); // you need this to prevent app from closing
}

private static async void SomeAsyncCode()
{
    // Use await here!
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    Console.WriteLine("Run Last");
    // Other async goodness...
}
```